# Не работают модальные окна с SSL сертификатом

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, site

Есть интернет магазин, я купил для него SSL сертификат, сделал переброс на [https://мойсатй.ру/](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B9.%D1%80%D1%83/)
Выбрал товар нажимаю кнопку купить, и в адресной строке появляться `#modal4`.
Если я уберу `https` и поставлю `http`, то всё замечательно работает, и модальное окно открывается, подскажите что мне делать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

При заходе на Ваш сайт по HTTPS, консоль хрома сразу выводит ошибки:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hypergift.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2015/12/01/11/just-cause-3.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
(index):234 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hypergift.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://steampay.com/screenshots/grand-theft-auto-v-4.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
(index):245 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hypergift.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://u.kanobu.ru/longreads/2016/2/10/c32fcf54-3c2b-4af3-9a0c-efdd818d57cf.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
(index):256 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hypergift.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://json.tv/public/images/general/2015/09/06/20150906235413-2840.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
(index):267 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hypergift.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://meownauts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1446481232_1280x720-cuu.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

При использовании SSL сертификата, все внешние ссылки в атрибутах src должны использовать протокол https.

**Не правильно:**

```
<img class="activator" src="http://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2015/12/01/11/just-cause-3.jpg">
```

**Правильно:**

```
<img class="activator" src="https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2015/12/01/11/just-cause-3.jpg">
```

**P.S.**
Еще у Вас есть ошибка JS, которую сразу видно в консоли хрома:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).awShowcase is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего где то на странице, а именно в скрипте, отвечающем за окна есть вызов каких то файлов без https и они блокируются каким нибудь антивирусом или браузером, впрочем последнее маловероятно. Попробуйте открыть код страницы (контра+u)в мозиле и поиском посмотреть, нет ли где http. И заменить на просто адрес без домена, начиная со слева

Comment: <a class="waves-effect right waves-light btn modal-trigger" style="border-radius: 20px; width: 547px; margin-top: 9px;" href="#modal3"></i>Купить за 100р</a></span> вот код.
Нет https там нету, это движок LazyPay.

Comment: Киньте ссылку на сайт

Comment: http://hypergift.ru/ - Там потом просто добавьте https если что.

Answer (score 0):

Всё решил, оказывается в JS был лишний код, его убрал и всё заработало. Всем спасибо.